# Predicate com CAST

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, swift, core-data

Acessando o banco de dados `.sqlite` via `sql` normalmente, posso utilizar a função `CAST('coluna' as decimal)`.

Via `NSPredicate` utilizando `CoreData`, como faço a mesma coisa? Possuo uma coluna do tipo `String` e preciso fazer um `cast` para `decimal`.

Comment: Só para entender: se é um decimal, por que o tipo da coluna é string? E por que você precisa fazer esse *cast* dentro do próprio *predicate*?

Comment: No momento está sendo tratado uma `latitude` e `longitude` dentro do banco como `String` por algumas outras operações que serão realizadas mais tarde. Por tal motivo eu teria de efetuar esse cast no próprio "Where"

Comment: Sim, eu entendi que você precisa destas colunas como decimal para criar suas condições. Só não entendi por que não salvar já estes valores em uma coluna do tipo decimal. Pra ser sincero, desconheço algo similar ao `CAST` diretamente no `Core Data`.

Comment: `decimal`? A que tipo de dados você está se referindo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim ter CAST em um NSPredicate.

A sintaxe é:

```
CAST(<o que vai ser convertido>, 'classe destino')
```

Exemplo:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"10.0", @"8.99"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CAST(self, 'NSNumber') > %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:9.0]];

NSLog(@"%@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Em seu caso, assumindo que a propriedade de sua entidade no CoreData seja "latitude":

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CAST(latitude, 'NSNumber') > %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:9.0]];
```

Mais exemplos aqui (Em inglês): http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1677163679/creating-an-advanced-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate